How to fix "User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system: statistics"?
I'm running Drupal 10.3.1. The Statistics module was deprecated with the 10.3 release. I uninstalled Statistics using drush (drush pmu statistics). The module was uninstalled without error, but now I occasionally see this warning in my log:

User warning: The following theme is missing from the file system:
statistics in
Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionPathResolver->getPathname() (line 63 of
/var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionPathResolver.php)
#0 /var/www/mysite/web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(166): _drupal_error_handler_real()
#1 [internal function]: _drupal_error_handler()
#2 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionPathResolver.php(63):
trigger_error()
#3 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionPathResolver.php(85):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionPathResolver->getPathname()
#4 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryParser.php(154):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionPathResolver->getPath()
#5 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php(87):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryParser->buildByExtension()
#6 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php(66):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->getLibraryDefinitions()
#7 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Cache/CacheCollector.php(149):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->resolveCacheMiss()
#8 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscovery.php(44):
Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheCollector->get()
#9 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscovery.php(58):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibrariesByExtension()
#10 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDependencyResolver.php(68):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName()
#11 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDependencyResolver.php(41):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->doGetDependencies()
#12 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDependencyResolver.php(87):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->getLibrariesWithDependencies()
#13 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/AssetResolver.php(113):
Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDependencyResolver->getMinimalRepresentativeSubset()
#14 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/AssetResolver.php(128):
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getLibrariesToLoad()
#15 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/system/src/Controller/CssAssetController.php(49):
Drupal\Core\Asset\AssetResolver->getCssAssets()
#16 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/system/src/Controller/AssetControllerBase.php(178):
Drupal\system\Controller\CssAssetController->getGroups()
#17 [internal function]: Drupal\system\Controller\AssetControllerBase->deliver()
#18 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123):
call_user_func_array()
#19 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(638): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
#20 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124):
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext()
#21 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97):
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext()
#22 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(181): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
#23 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(76): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw()
#24 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(53):
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle()
#25 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle()
#26 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php(28):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle()
#27 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/big_pipe/src/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php(32):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle()
#28 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(191):
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle()
#29 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(128):
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch()
#30 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(82):
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup()
#31 /var/www/mysite/web/modules/contrib/cleantalk/src/EventSubscriber/BootSubscriber.php(193):
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle()
#32 /var/www/mysite/web/core/modules/ban/src/BanMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\cleantalk\EventSubscriber\BootSubscriber->handle()
#33 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48):
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle()
#34 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle()
#35 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/AjaxPageState.php(36):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle()
#36 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/StackedHttpKernel.php(51):
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle()
#37 /var/www/mysite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(741): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle()
#38 /var/www/mysite/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle()
#39 {main}

The location associated with the warning:

https://www.mysite.org/sites/default/files/css/css_mrHz6wTZTs8Bzl8OQaIsGSa72DEwAOQxloPCPaziamc.css?delta=0&include=eJx1kEFuxCAMRS-UGaTRLHobZIgnseLYCJu26enLYpRKEV1h3gPL31lZa9LvMOMLGvuU3yCSMAmGy32ywxz3kMBwSlCdtpAZzI77AO1oBgta71oxiNYdmH7OVwtrAr6ZH7318qbPx8dVYItZdSPsx16YQDKGEYxnCkYQB94ClJT9VlpiypM5OJlTtjDXVoDvf-Qyuujcw7aC9UW2hrOKq35iJXEUH3rrGdlyRZSxb6WokZP-67FaSzay4x99TRi_VnL8BdybuAw&language=en&theme=mytheme

I don't see any remnants of the module in my themes folder. How can I fix this warning?

What kind of HTTP request is affiliated with the warning?

https://www.mysite.org/sites/default/files/css/css_mrHz6wTZTs8Bzl8OQaIsGSa72DEwAOQxloPCPaziamc.css?delta=0&include=eJx1kEFuxCAMRS-UGaTRLHobZIgnseLYCJu26enLYpRKEV1h3gPL31lZa9LvMOMLGvuU3yCSMAmGy32ywxz3kMBwSlCdtpAZzI77AO1oBgta71oxiNYdmH7OVwtrAr6ZH7318qbPx8dVYItZdSPsx16YQDKGEYxnCkYQB94ClJT9VlpiypM5OJlTtjDXVoDvf-Qyuujcw7aC9UW2hrOKq35iJXEUH3rrGdlyRZSxb6WokZP-67FaSzay4x99TRi_VnL8BdybuAw&language=en&theme=mytheme

That is information for the question above rather than for a comment.

Also from your logs it would be good to get an understand of who or what is making that request. This seems related to https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3377310 and may be a bug report on its own.

It's bingbot. Here's the line from my web server log:
157.55.39.48 - - [16/Jul/2024:15:56:27 -0400] "GET /sites/default/files/css/css_mrHz6wTZTs8Bzl8OQaIsGSa72DEwAOQxloPCPaziamc.css?delta=0&language=en&theme=mytheme&include=eJx1kEFuxCAMRS-[snipped for length]-Qyuujcw7aC9UW2hrOKq35iJXEUH3rrGdlyRZSxb6WokZP-67FaSzay4x99TRi_VnL8BdybuAw HTTP/1.1" 200 5164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/116.0.1938.76 Safari/537.36"

I’m voting to close this question because it should be a bug report.
